# Git: Update my remote git to be the same as my local

Tags: git, github

I'm relatively new on git, so keep that in mind.

So, I have three branches:

- master
- b1
- b2

This is how my local and remote repository look like.

At one point, I merged b2 in to the master, and deleted b2 (all of this on my local repository). Lastly, I pushed my master to my origin/master.

My questions are:

1. Now I want to delete b2 from the remote repo. How do I do that?
2. Is this generally proper practice?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Since your version of git is unknown, this will work:

#### Deleting local branch

```
$ git branch -d branch_name
```

#### Deleting remote branch

```
$ git push -d <remote> <branch_name>
```

For recent versions there is a `--delete` flag, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/1333212)

2) If you are working in a team you can either let the remote branches be there and do a cleanup of merged branches from time to time or if that is not needed then IMO just to as you are doing.

Avoid leaving *lost* branches polluting your remote as you can always go back to a specific commit, no need to keep the old branches.